# Sum of two empty matrices

Tags: matrices

Is the sum of two empty matrices also an empty matrix? I think it does, but I am not sure. Can you help me? Just a yes or no will suffice, thank you.

Comment: what is an "empty matrix"?

Comment: @M.U. A 0x0 matrix with zero columns and zero rows, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Empty_matrices

Comment: then I say "Yes".

Comment: You can add only matrices with the same dimensions, and in that case the result is a matrix with the same dimensions, i.e. $0\times 0$ matrix. So, Yes!

Comment: @xhimi Thanks, +1

Answer (score 0):

No, it says it right there in the article, if $A$ is $3 \times 0$ and $B$ is $0 \times 3$ then $AB=0$ and is $3\times 3$ (as it has neither 0 rows or columns, it's not an empty matrix).

**EDIT:** I misread sum as product. The answer is yes: matrices must coincide in dimensions to be added, so the sum of two empty matrices will have 0 rows or columns.